# Redis-objects Ruby gem, how to retrieve Redis list and iterate?

Tags: ruby, redis, redis-objects

I'm trying to use [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) Ruby gem to store some Redis data in lists.

I am able to create a list by following the [example](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects#lists) in the documentation.

I am able to find the list from Redis using lrange. Not sure if that is the best way, I couldn't find a method provided by redis-objects.

Initially when I iterate the elements in the list I get the elements in the form of Hashes.

However after I get the list using lrange those are not hashes and I cannot access the data.

What would be the appropriate way to find the list and get the items in hash form?

You can see the code below and the outputs from the console.

```
@list = Redis::List.new('list_name', :marshal => true)
@list << {:name => "Nate", :city => "San Diego"}
@list.each do |el|
    puts el
    puts el.class
    puts "#{el[:name]} lives in #{el[:city]}"
end

redis = Redis.current
@list = redis.lrange("list_name", 0, -1)
@list.each do |el|
    puts el
    puts el.class
    puts "#{el[:name]} lives in #{el[:city]}"
end
```

Each of the puts:

```
{:name=>"Nate", :city=>"San Diego"}
Hash
Nate lives in San Diego
{:  nameI"  Nate:ET:    cityI"San Diego;T
String
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 349ms

TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. The text below, from the Gem documentation explains it!

> There is a Ruby class that maps to each Redis type, with methods for
>   each Redis API command. **Note that calling new does not imply it's
>   actually a "new" value - it just creates a mapping between that Ruby
>   object and the corresponding Redis data structure**, which may already
>   exist on the redis-server.

So I don't need to use lrange to get to the list. Using `Redis::List.new('list_name', :marshal => true)` will get me a handle to the list. Then I can iterate, add or remove items from the list.

Reading is helpful...